# How can I build a bootable ISO with my specific customisations?

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, usb

I've been given the task to create a bootable iso that can be used on a USB key and eventually over PXE.

I need to use Ubuntu 20.0.4 server mode with no GUI.

I have no problem using the standard IOS from Ubuntu but have no idea how to use an answer file (preseed file?) to complete the install and also how I can add various tools via 'apt-get install'?  We also have a specific piece of software from a vendor to add.

What do you use to do this please so I can do some research?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For bare metal installs of Ubuntu 20.04 server I user the automatised server installs.. Then I plug in the standard ubuntu 20.03 iso and the cloud-init cidata USB and it does an unattended boot.     If your motherboard has IPMI that it will probably support remote mounting of ISO images and this can be used remotely.

[Automated Server Installs](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall)

This allows you to configure cloud-init files that detail what and how you want the machine to be install and provisioned.  Its very powerful.

if you install a machine manually it will store a copy of the cloud-init file to recreate that machine in /var/log/installer in a file called auto install-user-data.  Thats a good starting point for what you need todo.

[Autoinstall Quickstart guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart)